# Attach an image into a Django Model

Tags: python, django, image, model

Making a basic Q&A site and want to associate each question with an image (admin uploaded) and if there is no respective image, puts it with a default "No Image" placeholder.

I have two models, Question and Answer (see below). Each question needs to have an image associated with it, so I thought the best way was to attach attribute ImageField with the Question model.

```
#models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    picture = models.ImageField(height_field = '250',
                                width_field = '200',
                                upload_to = 'images')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I runserver though, tells me to download Python Imaging Library, and when I do get an error (different problem).

Taking a step back, what is the best way to add an image to a model in Django?

Comment: I think using `ImageField` is a perfectly good way to add an image to a model in Django. If you can't install Python Imaging Library (PIL) for one reason or another, you could also try just using a `FileField`.

Comment: I believe you're using height_field and width_field incorrectly. It's supposed to be a string with the name of a field you want to put the specified value. So height_field='myheightfield'. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

Comment: thanks, realized after I tried to run the program and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Forget PIL...

Use a location URL DB entry. Instead of having an ImageField(), use

```
picturepath = models.CharField(255)
```

that contains a URL to the static location of the image.

so if STATIC_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/static/"
and picturepath = "images/poots.png"

Then, pass that information along in the view, and use this in the template:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ question.picturepath }}">
```

will provide

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/static/images/poots.png">
```